# examples of functions that are not random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have been reading the definition of the random variable in R. G. Gallager's book, entitled "Stochastic processes: theory for applications". (Please see Definition 1.3.4 on Page 11/69 in 
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap01.pdf)

In the definition, Gallager mentioned that "second: the mapping $X(\omega)$ must have the property that $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}$ is an event for each $x\in\Omega$. third: every finite set of rv's $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ has the property that $\{\omega\in\Omega:X_1(\omega)\leq x_1,\cdots,X_n(\omega)\leq x_n\}$ is an event for each $x_1,\cdots,x_n$". 
He explained in footnote 13, that the statements about the events are technical limitations and one should know that not all functions from $\Omega$ to $\Omega$ are rv’s.

However, I still do not understand. Why does rv need to satisfy these properties? Are there any examples of functions that are not rv's?

Thanks!

Comment: This is equivalent on asking "do exist subsets of $\Omega$ which is not an event?". If you have such a subset, then take consider its characteristic function as a map which is not a rv.

Comment: @Crostul I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the random variable $X:(\Omega,F,P)\to (\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$ to be measurable meaning that $X^{-1}(\vartheta)\in F$ for all $\vartheta\in B(\mathbb{R})$ so that we can meaningfully assign probabilities: $$P[\{\omega: X(\omega)\in\vartheta\}].$$

Such an $X$ which is not measurable will therefore not be a random variable.